# Is it possible to create a true Dialog in Xamarin Forms WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Dialogs created in Xamarin Forms (e.g. Alert Dialog or a custom Dialog) are shown within the bounds of the application window. This is fine for mobile devices but on the Windows Desktop one would expect to have a true Dialog (e.g. MessageBox, Custom Dialog) that has its own window.
Is this possible with Xamarin Forms WPF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/other/wpf), the Xamarin.Forms WPF support is still in Preview, so will not be as complete/stable as Android/iOS/UWP support.

> This is a preview, so you should expect that not everything is
> production ready. Not all NuGet packages for Xamarin.Forms are ready
> for WPF, and some features might not be fully working.

I find a [forms-wpf-progress](https://github.com/mohachouch/forms-wpf-progress/blob/master/Status.md) file and there is nothing like the `MessageBox, Custom Dialog` as you mentioned in the question. So I think it is not possible to create such a thing so far.

Maybe you can use a [DependencyService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/) to add your own support for features in WPF.